# Open a file selection dialog in a specific folder

Tags: python

To open a file selection dialog and show only specific extensions, I'm using one of the templates that come with blender, (Text -> Templates -> Python -> Operator File Export):

```
class SelectFile(bpy.types.Operator, bpy_extras.io_utils.ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "demo.select_file" 
    bl_label = "Select a file"

    filename_ext = ".txt"
    filter_glob = bpy.props.StringProperty(default='*.txt', options={'HIDDEN'}, maxlen=255)

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.filepath)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I couldn't find out how to open the dialog in a specific folder.
Thanks!

Comment: Would suggest invoking it via code `bpy.ops.import_test.some_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT', filepath="/tmp")`, or in your  ui as `row.operator("import_test.some_data").filepath="/tmp"`

Comment: Thanks!! How did you find it out?